# docker volume : data lost when container is removed or stopped and then restarted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-volume

I'm have mounted 2 containers :

- Mongo : as the database -> the volume is mounted on a specified path

> docker run --hostname raw-data-mongo --name=raw-data-mongo
>   --network=our-network -p 27017:27017 -v data/db/raw-data-db:/data/db -d mongo

- Nodejs: save some data to mongodb

> docker run -d -p 80:3001 --name=raw-data-container
>   --network=our-network -v /data/db/raw-data-db:/data/db raw-data-api

But any time I save data (using my node app container, connecting to mongo container) and then remove my node container and restart, I can't retrieve the data I saved.

How should I do to mount a volume that is independent of the node, and if possible independent from any container?

I wish I could remove and restart containers and still be able to retrieve my data

Comment: Did you previously created `data/db/raw-data-db` directory before deploying the container?

Comment: @gypsyCoder : no

Answer (score 1):

You can run use `-v` to specify the volume against which you want your docker deployment to save your data. Two things you should keep in mind is, one is that the docker that you are running should be exposing the `-v` and using this to store its data (mongodb does this, and so does most projects) and another the persistence volume path passed with `-v` should exist and the docker process should have write permissions on it.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thanks for your reply and review. 
One thing is still not clear for me :

the mongo-container needs a volume to store data: OK

the node-container reach the mongo-container to save data, but as it doesn't save data himself, I don't get why when I restart my mongo-container, and reach mongo to get all data, I get an empty response

Comment: Because your mongo volume is temporary, it assigns a new one unless you specify -v. Use something like docker-compose if you want a more structured set of containers and volumes

Comment: sorry, I meant : I don't get why when I restart my node-container, and reach mongo to get all data, I get an empty response

Comment: Are you providing the same `volume` path when you restart the mongo-container? If you are not restarting mongo-container but just your node-container, please make sure that you are connecting to the right mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as following

Step 1: Make the directory

```
$HOME/data/db/raw-data-db
```

Step 2: Then assign the volume

```
docker run --hostname raw-data-mongo --name=raw-data-mongo
--network=our-network -p 27017:27017 -v $HOME/data/db/raw-data-db:/data/db -d mongo
```

In this way, your data will be persisted for mongodb in the volume. For node.js use different volume.

Comment: thanks for your help, unfortunately it didn't work. I still can't reach the data I have saved after restarting my node container. 
I also tried with the option : --volumes-from raw-data-mongo 
I still don't get why restarting my node container cause the "lost" of data on my mongo container...